# Como fazer um mock de useState no React

Tags: react, firebase, testes, react-hooks, mock

Estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar fazer um mock de um useState que recebe notas no React, o setNotes. Estou utilizando firebase, então essas notas são uma array de docs. Assim está meu componente:

```
export default function HomePage() {
    const { user, signOut } = useContext(AuthGoogleContext);
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState({});
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const userSigned = user ? JSON.parse(user) : null;

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (authObj) => {
            if (authObj) {
                const q = query(
                    collection(db, "notes"),
                    where("uid", "==", auth.currentUser.uid)
                );
                const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
                if (querySnapshot && querySnapshot.docs && querySnapshot.docs.length) {
                    const notesData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                        const note = doc.data();
                        return {
                            ...note,
                            id: doc.id,
                            uid: auth.currentUser.uid,
                        };
                    });
                    console.log(notesData);

                    setNotes(notesData);
                }

                return { querySnapshot, array: [] };

            } else {
                signOut();
            }

            return () => {
                unsubscribe();
            };
        });
        // NOTE: Run effect once on component mount, please
        // recheck dependencies if effect is updated.
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
```

Para mim, aparentemente está tudo correto, o problema é no teste. Já tentei de várias maneiras fazer o mock do useState, porém em todas as vezes dá o seguinte erro:

```
  expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: [{"conteudo": "nota 1", "id": 1, "timestamp": {"nanoseconds": 837277, "seconds": 62527}, "titulo": "titulo 1", "uid": "aw69hf"}, {"conteudo": "nota 2", "id": 2, "timestamp": {"nanoseconds": 837277, "seconds": 62527}, "titulo": "titulo 2", "uid": "aw69hf"}]

    Number of calls: 0
```

Ou seja, o setNotes não é chamado.

Já tentei utilizar tanto o jest.spyOn quanto o jest.mock para o useState.
Atualmente meu teste está assim:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import HomePage from "../pages/home/Home";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthGoogleContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import { getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth } from "../lib/firebase-config";

jest.mock('react', ()=>({
    ...jest.requireActual('react'),
    useState: jest.fn()
  }))
import { useState } from 'react';

beforeEach(()=>{
    useState.mockImplementation(jest.requireActual('react').useState);
  })

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
})

jest.mock("firebase/firestore", () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual("firebase/firestore");
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        getDocs: jest.fn(() => ({ docs: [] })),
    };
});

jest.mock("../lib/firebase-config", () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("../lib/firebase-config"),
    auth: {
        onAuthStateChanged: jest.fn(),
        currentUser: {
            uid: "aw69hf",
        },
    },
}));

function setupWithUser(user) {
    const contextValue = {
        user: JSON.stringify(user),
        signOut: jest.fn(),
    };
    return contextValue;
}
```

O teste em específico:

```
it("calls setNotes", () => {
    const userSigned = { displayName: "Outro", uid: "aw69hf" };
    // autenticação do usuário mockada
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.mockImplementation((callback) => {
        callback(userSigned);
    });
    // componente renderizado uma vez
    render(
        <MemoryRouter>
            <AuthGoogleContext.Provider value={setupWithUser(userSigned)}>
                <HomePage />
            </AuthGoogleContext.Provider>
        </MemoryRouter>
    );

    // mock de notas feito
    const mockNote1 = {
        id: 1,
        data: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            conteudo: "nota 1",
            timestamp: { seconds: 62527, nanoseconds: 837277 },
            titulo: "titulo 1",
            uid: "aw69hf",
        }),
    };

    const mockNote2 = {
        id: 2,
        data: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            conteudo: "nota 2",
            timestamp: { seconds: 62527, nanoseconds: 837277 },
            titulo: "titulo 2",
            uid: "aw69hf",
        }),
    };

    const setNotes = jest.fn();

    const mockSnapshot = { docs: [mockNote1, mockNote2] };

    useState.mockImplementation(()=>[mockSnapshot, setNotes])

    console.log("setNotes called:", setNotes.mock.calls);
    expect(setNotes).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
        { id: 1, ...mockNote1.data(), uid: userSigned.uid },
        { id: 2, ...mockNote2.data(), uid: userSigned.uid },
    ]);
})
```

Ainda estou começando a entender os mocks de fato, então não consigo mais pensar em outras formas de identificar este erro pois já testei todas as recomendações possíveis.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Parece que você está tendo problemas ao tentar testar a chamada de setNotes dentro do componente HomePage. Uma abordagem mais eficaz seria simular a chamada do setNotes após a renderização do componente e, em seguida, verificar se a renderização foi atualizada corretamente.

Aqui está uma versão modificada do seu teste:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import HomePage from "../pages/home/Home";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthGoogleContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import { getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth } from "../lib/firebase-config";

jest.mock("firebase/firestore", () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual("firebase/firestore");
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    getDocs: jest.fn(() => ({ docs: [] })),
  };
});

jest.mock("../lib/firebase-config", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../lib/firebase-config"),
  auth: {
    onAuthStateChanged: jest.fn(),
    currentUser: {
      uid: "aw69hf",
    },
  },
}));

function setupWithUser(user) {
  const contextValue = {
    user: JSON.stringify(user),
    signOut: jest.fn(),
  };
  return contextValue;
}

it("calls setNotes", async () => {
  const userSigned = { displayName: "Outro", uid: "aw69hf" };

  // autenticação do usuário mockada
  auth.onAuthStateChanged.mockImplementation((callback) => {
    callback(userSigned);
  });

  // mock de notas feito
  const mockNote1 = {
    id: 1,
    data: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      conteudo: "nota 1",
      timestamp: { seconds: 62527, nanoseconds: 837277 },
      titulo: "titulo 1",
      uid: "aw69hf",
    }),
  };

  const mockNote2 = {
    id: 2,
    data: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      conteudo: "nota 2",
      timestamp: { seconds: 62527, nanoseconds: 837277 },
      titulo: "titulo 2",
      uid: "aw69hf",
    }),
  };

  const mockSnapshot = { docs: [mockNote1, mockNote2] };

  // Mock useState
  const setNotesMock = jest.fn();
  jest.spyOn(React, "useState").mockReturnValue([mockSnapshot, setNotesMock]);

  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <AuthGoogleContext.Provider value={setupWithUser(userSigned)}>
        <HomePage />
      </AuthGoogleContext.Provider>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  // Espera que setNotes tenha sido chamado após a renderização
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(setNotesMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
      { id: 1, ...mockNote1.data(), uid: userSigned.uid },
      { id: 2, ...mockNote2.data(), uid: userSigned.uid },
    ]);
  });
});
```

Nesta versão, eu usei jest.spyOn para mockar o useState, e usei waitFor para esperar que a renderização do componente tenha sido concluída antes de verificar se setNotes foi chamado corretamente. Certifique-se de que o código dentro do useEffect está sendo chamado corretamente, pois isso pode impactar o resultado do teste.